# How to create Dynamic Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
lst = ['SymbolA','SymbolB', 'SymbolC' .... 'SymbolN']
```

I want to create dynamic Dataframe in Python Pandas.

```
for i in lst:
   data = SomeFunction(lst[i]) # This will return dataframe of 10 x 100

   lst[i]+str(i) = pd.DataFrame(data)

pd.Concat(SymbolA1,SymbolB1,SymbolC1,SymbolD1)
```

Anyone can help on how to create the dataframe dynamically to achieve as per the requirements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: Why don't you directly do `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(SomeFunction()) for i in lst])`?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help, as i understood from this.

```
gbl = globals()

lst = ['SymbolA','SymbolB', 'SymbolC' .... 'SymbolN']

for i in lst:

   data = SomeFunction(lst[i])

   gbl[lst[i]+str(i)] = pd.Dataframe(data)
```

this will create a df dynamically . for accessing those df you need to run code like this.

```
gbl[lst[i]+str(i)]
```

try this..

Answer (score 0):

You input has to be like below:

```
lst = ({'data':['SymbolA','SymbolB', 'SymbolC', 'SymbolN']})

print pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Comment: datadf = SomeFunction(lst[i]) This will return some values of 10col and 100 rows as Dataframe and then this datadf will be added into final Dataframe.